# Azure Synapse Pipeline Date Expression - Last Monday

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I have the following azure function that is supposed to retrieve the date of the previous Monday. It works fine except for if the current date is a monday. I need the function to still retrieve the previous monday date if it is Monday or Tuesday. This is due to the time not being updated until middle of day tuesday.

`@{formatDateTime( subtractFromTime( utcNow(), sub(dayOfWeek(utcNow()),1), 'Day' ), 'yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00' )}`

I am still learning Azure synapse so I am not sure if I can write an IF statement that accomplishes this or if there is a better way to write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced the above and able to get the desired result by using the below dynamic content.

```
@if(greater(dayOfWeek(utcnow()),1),formatDateTime(addDays(subtractFromTime(utcnow(),dayOfWeek(utcnow()),'Day'),1),'yyyy/MM/dd'),formatDateTime(addDays(subtractFromTime(utcnow(),dayOfWeek(utcnow()),'Day'),-6),'yyyy/MM/dd'))
```

- The day of week for a monday from last sunday is 1, so I am checking the current date's day of week is greater than monday or not.
- **If it is greater** (Today is not a Monday), then **I am giving last Monday by adding 1 day to the last Sunday**.
- **If it is not**, then **I am subtracting -6 from the last Sunday which is the previous Monday**.

This will work for all days, but we need to change the condition and the number which we are adding and subtracting as per the day we required.

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

If you want the result to be Monday even though current date is Monday or Tuesday, then give the expression for Tuesday also in the above condition using `or`.